# Begin importing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, import, drop

I have this query that was originally for Oracle now I'm converting it to SQL and I got this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'importing'.

I'm also connecting to another SQL server.

Begin importing data

```
-- Import Realmast
USE TAXPAYER

DROP TABLE VISION_REALMAST1
SELECT * 
INTO dbo.VISION_REALMAST
FROM [TOMSQLVISION].[VISION_2020].[REAL_PROP].[REALMAST]
--DROP THE PUBLIC EMPLOYEES
DELETE FROM dbo.VISION_REALMAST1 
WHERE REM_INET_SUPPRESS = 1 
-- Update the GIS ID field in realmast
UPDATE dbo.VISION_REALMAST1
SET REM_GIS_ID = CAST(CAST(REM_MBLU_MAP AS INT) AS VARCHAR(20))  +'-'+ CAST(CAST(REM_MBLU_BLOCK AS INT) AS VARCHAR(20))
```

Comment: Is 'Begin importing data' part of the query?? It's the only place I see the word importing which makes me think that you should exclude that line or comment it out.

Comment: I commented it out.  As of right now it is working.  I'm testing it on the SQL server where the final tables are being stored and I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  I think this is what you are asking about.